# Issues with the aurelia-tabbed project

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying to include [aurelia-tabbed](https://github.com/jawa-the-hutt/aurelia-tabbed) in my aurelia project (of which I think I have the latest version, but I can't find a version number anywhere). I have a problem however, because I'm using a bundle of my app and vendor js, and I don't know how to include the package.

I've tried adding this in my aurelia.json in build > bundles > (vendor) > dependencies:

```
      {
        "name": "aurelia-tabbed",
        "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-tabbed/dist/amd",
        "main": "index",
        "resources": ["assets/tabs.css"]
      },
```

However, while this compiles, I cannot run the webpage. It gives me errors in the console (even before I add any of the tabbed tags):

```
DEBUG [aurelia] Configured plugin aurelia-tabbed.

vendor-bundle.js:5700 GET http://localhost:9001/analysis/test-page/node_modules/aurelia-tabbed/dist/amd/tab-headers.js 
vendor-bundle.js:5700 GET http://localhost:9001/analysis/test-page/node_modules/aurelia-tabbed/dist/amd/tabs-wrapper.js 
vendor-bundle.js:5700 GET http://localhost:9001/analysis/test-page/node_modules/aurelia-tabbed/dist/amd/tab-content.js 

vendor-bundle.js:1395 Unhandled rejection Error: Script error for "aurelia-tabbed/tab-headers"
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (http://localhost:9001/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:3907:17)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (http://localhost:9001/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:5477:36)
```

The three calls all result in 404's (which is normal, because the node_modules path is located at the root).
However: why are the three calls even made? Aren't the files supposed to be bundled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `aurelia.json` file, you need to list all resources of the plugin. Try the following:

```
      {
        "name": "aurelia-tabbed",
        "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-tabbed/dist/amd",
        "main": "index",
        "resources": [
          "tab-content.html",
          "tab-headers.html",
          "tabs-wrapper.html",
          "assets/tabs.css"
        ]
      },
```

Comment: I just gave it a try, and it still didn't work, same errors :-(

Comment: Really strange, just created a blank Aurelia CLI project with this plugin and it works fine for me. Which CLI version do you use? Is it a TypeScript project? Webpack?

Comment: How do I check the version? There's no version file or whatever... It's Typescript, and while I don't see the term webpack anywhere (why must everything be hidden... a colleague who left set this up), it's probably that

Comment: Ah, no webpack, just aurelia cli

Comment: You are correct that in a vanilla project, it works... dang it, I'll have to investigate all the details of our larger project now

Comment: Ugh. In my vanilla project it also calls the files it needs with separate http requests, but in my real project (where the URLs have a folder structure), the files get loaded not from the root, but from the directory of my script/node_modules and so on... So: they just don't get bundled (or the module has no idea what bundling is all about)

Comment: Aha! Instead of just requiring the html files in the "resources", when I also add the js files, it does work!             "resources": [
              "tab-content.js",
              "tab-headers.js",
              "tabs-wrapper.js",
              "tab-content.html",
              "tab-headers.html",
              "tabs-wrapper.html",
              "assets/tabs.css"
            ]